# Firebase Date vs Timestamp

Tags: typescript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm building an app with Ionic v6 and Angular using Firebase Firestore as the cloud datastore.  I have a defined interface with a 'Date' object:

```
export interface PuzzleInfo {
       puzzleAnswers: string[];
       puzzleTitle: string;
       deployed: boolean;
       deployDate: Date;
       status?: string;
    }
```

When the data gets written to Firestore it is "converted" into a Timestamp type of [seconds, nanoseconds].  Then, when I read the data back into the same object definition, the 'deployDate' is unusable as a Date type; a console log displays 'invalid date' and I can't use any of the Date methods/functions on it.  Even though the data type is "Date" the actual content of the item coming in from the DB isn't valid for a Date.

I create a Timestamp interface that mimics the Firestore data type

```
export interface Timestamp {
   seconds: number;
   nanoseconds: number;
}
```

then, in my TS code I convert/cast the incoming object into a timestamp object and then back into a date:

```
public puzzle: PuzzleInfo[]

<< read data from Firestore >>
const fbTimestamp = this.puzzle.deployDate as unknown as Timestamp;
this.depDate = new Date(fbTimestamp.seconds * 1000).toISOString();
```

This gives me what I need in the const fbTimestamp and I can then access just the seconds part into a Date.  Is there an easier/better way to do this?  I am not directly converting the Date object to a FB Timestamp object; from what I can tell FB does that for me.  Is there a way to prevent that conversion?  I know I can make the deployDate a string and store it in the DB as a string, and then convert it back and forth.

While this works, it does seem very convoluted and prone to mistakes in the future.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easier/better way to do this?

With the way you have the data defined now, not really.  Data type conversions are pretty common with databases, though.  It's not really as bad as you imagine - you will certainly encounter far more difficult and problematic things in other parts of your app.  Just write a data converter function and use that whenever you need it.  It's not prone to mistakes if you unit test that function well.  Firestore even has a TypeScript API for exactly this: [FirestoreDataConverter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter).

> Is there a way to prevent that conversion?

Not really, as long as you are using Date objects.  If you absolutely must have a Date object in your code, then you will be converting to and from it every time you want to read and write.  You might have a better time using a number instead of a Date, then converting that number only when you absolutely need something else derived from it.  You may not even need Date at all if you plan well.

Using a string for a date type is generally a bad idea, unless you want to commit to an ISO format that has a convenient converter.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, you confirmed what I was thinking.  I chose to convert the data in place immediately after the read:  puzzle.deployDate = new Date(dbData.deployDate as unknown as Timestamp * 1000);  << pseudo code >>   From what I can tell I don't have to convert it on the write; I do a db.collection().set() with the array that includes the Date item and it looks like Firebase converts it to it's own Timestamp format.  Thanks for the info.